# How can I Enable\Disable all subcontrols of a table?

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a checkBox, which when it's checked i want to enable a table and its subcontrols and when it's disabled I want to do the opposite.

I have already understand that I have to iterate all subControls of the table, and my question is if there is any nice and generic way of doing it.

Thanks in advance,

oz.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with **[jQuery](http://jquery.com)**. Let's say that your HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleControls(this)"/>Controls Disabled
<table id="myTable">
 <tr>
  <td>Name: <input type="text" /></td>
  <td>Select: <input type="radio" /></td>
 </tr> .....
```

The toggleControls() function to disable/enable **all the controls** inside the table (*this means all textboxes, buttons, checkboxes, radio buttons and dropdowns*) looks like this:

```
<script>
   function toggleControls(e){
     $('#myTable input,select,textarea').attr('disabled',e.checked);
   }
</script>
```

jQuery's css selectors make that one line to disable/enable the controls possible. With plain old javascript, the function would look like this:

```
var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
var controls= myTable.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
// Repeat the previous line for "select" and "textarea"
for(i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
    control = controls[i];
    control.disabled = !control.disabled;        
}
```

Comment: How can I iterate the sub tables inside the main table? they have no tagName

Comment: Are you going to use plain javascript or jQuery? Can you post your HTML, so that I can a better idea of what your are trying to accomplish?

Comment: For the jQuery way, just add a selection of $("#myTable table'), this will get all the subtables within the table that has an ID. For plain old javascript, myTable.getElementsByTagName("table") would do the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot easier to do with with a selector and a class name using a framework, for example (using Prototype.js).

When this item is clicked, enable all items with class of 'mycontrols'.

```
$('containerDiv').select('.mycontrols').each(function(element){element.disabled=false})
```